# DNS & .local domain 18.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, dhcp, avahi

I am trying to join Ubuntu laptops to our domain company.local (Yes I know .local is bad practice)

I am having some issues with only what I can assume is DNS. I can't ping the domain controller (dc.company.local) but I can ping other devices in a Foward Lookup Zone (mobiledevice.company.net) so this has to lead me to think Avahi is the issue.

In my research Avahi reserves .local for the local machine? So I have edited  `domain-name=local` to `domain-name=alocal` under `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`

I have also edited my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` from:

`files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4`

to:

`files dns mdns4_minimal mdns4`

My understanding is this should say to Ubuntu, use the host file and then the DNS server (Which is being given out by DHCP).

But I cannot resolve any names on my network ending in `.local`

Apologies if the formatting is weird this is my fist "proper" post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to update `\etc\systemd\resolved.conf` with my dns and domain information.

Comment: Exactly what did you add? What for?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with systemd-resolved (which is what Ubuntu 18.04 usually uses for name lookup). For me, the following entry in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` fixed those issues:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't do it for me even if I do jiggle the order around! Now I get a "Temporary failure in name resolution" for the DC. I can still ping other machines with a different DNS suffix.